# converting an enum to a list or sequence or generic collection type in F#

Tags: .net, f#

I have a type that is either a `Dictionary<string,Node<'a>>*Edge<'a> list` or a `ConcurrentDictionary<string,Node<'a>>*Edge<'a> list`.  I am trying to create a `get_nodes` function, but when I call `.Values` from the `Dictionary` and the `ConcurrentDictionary`, the functions return different types!

So I need to somehow convert both of the types into the same type for F# to compile...

The type given by `Dictionary.Values` is `Dictionary'2.ValueCollection<string,Node<'a>>` while the type yielded by `ConcurrentDictionary` is `ICollection<Node<'a>>`.

I figured out that both types have a "GetEnumerator()" function.  What I need to do is somehow turn the enumerator into a seq or list, etc.

Here is my code:

```
   static member get_nodes (g:Graph<'a>) = 
        match g with 
        | Dictionary_Graph(nd,el) -> let n = nd.Values
                                     let enum = n.GetEnumerator()


        | ConcurrentDictionary_Graph(nd,el) -> let n = nd.Values
                                               let enum = n.GetEnumerator()
```

How do I pull the data out of the enum variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably used to C# which would auto upcast the ValueCollection to an ICollection (which ValueCollection implements). F# does not do this, so you must manually cast the result of Dictionary.Values to ICollection.

```
let n = nd.Values :> ICollection<Node<'a>>
```

Full method would look something like this:

```
static member get_nodes (g:Graph<'a>) = 
    match g with 
    | Dictionary_Graph(nd,el) ->
        nd.Values :> ICollection<Node<'a>>
    | ConcurrentDictionary_Graph(nd,el) ->
        nd.Values
```

From what I understand, F# does not auto-upcast because of the way that the auto type inference engine works. It's irritating when you're used to C#, but it's a price worth paying to get automatic type inferencing. Also consider that in C#, you would have to specify the return type up front on the method, which makes it easy for C# to do the cast for you. F# engine infers the return type based on what you actually return, so the safest thing is to not make assumptions about how you want it cast.

Not general consensus, but my opinion: I hope they will add auto upcasting of return values for specific cases (like output type is declared ahead of time or to make branches conform like above), but it's a minor irritation for now.

**Update** (from question in comments)

`ICollection<T>` should now be directly usable as a sequence since it implements `IEnumerable<T>`. In this case auto-upcasting actually does work. :)

```
myGraph
|> Graph.get_nodes 
|> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
```

Comment: Hopefully they DON"T add it. Explicit cast code is better and more clear. Automatic casting and all that magic stuff makes harder to reason about the code, not just for F# type inference, also for the dev type inference.

Comment: @Gustavo. Disagree. Try using libraries like Automapper or RavenDB which expect `Expression<Func<T, obj>>` for a type-safe property specification. Because there's no upcasting, you can't make it work in F# without [significant expression mangling code](https://fsnotebook.net/notebook/fssnip-c7/Using_AutoMapper_with_F).

Comment: @KaseySpeakman: Looks like most of that code is dedicated to converting F# quotations to LINQ expressions...not sure what it has to do with auto-casting.

Comment: @Daniel, that was the method they chose to resolve the issue. However, if you tried to use the more basic method of passing in `fun x -> x.Property` that would fail to compile (except the rare case where Property is of type `obj`). And adding `x.Property :> obj` changes the expression type, which throws when the expression is parsed by libraries expecting a property access, not a cast. To make it work, you have to manually construct an `Expression<Func<T, obj>>` and pass that in.

Comment: ... or use an alternate (non-type-safe) method. But not all libraries provide one.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I think that will get my code to work.  Any ideas on getting a list or sequence out of the `enum` variable?

Comment: @bordeo, `ICollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you should be able to use it directly as a sequence. In that case upcasting does work automatically. :)

Comment: @KaseySpeakman: C# inserts a boxing cast too ([see .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TVFXyK)).

Comment: @Daniel, that's not typical usage and would probably crash as well. See [this .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jYMfHL) for typical usage. Most are wired to look for `MemberAccess` specifically, then get the name of the accessed property, otherwise crash. This strategy was an answer to the problem of passing in a string for the property name and losing the ability to find-by-reference and rename-refactor those instances.

Comment: The key difference between our fiddles is that mine is inspecting a value type property and yours a reference type property. C# auto-inserts the boxing conversion for value types, but not for reference types. F# requires explicit boxing for both. A library that uses expressions in this way should be able to handle the conversion, otherwise it doesn't support value type properties. If the support is there, F# is on par with C# for this usage.

Comment: @Daniel, that's semantics. When I try to use most libraries taking expressions from F#, either it doesn't compile (as with `fun x -> x.Property`), or it crashes (as with `fun x -> x.Property :> obj`). [Here is a typical example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5puzuh) that will crash with the latter. Whereas in C# `x => x.Property` will certainly compile and not crash when calling the same method. The libraries could be written differently, yes, but handling every edge case lambda which could possible be reduced to a property access is not a great solution either.

Comment: Handling properties that return a value type is an edge case? The library could be written differently indeed.

Comment: @Daniel. Umm, well, you are absolutely right. I just tried to make a test case for the failure which I encountered recently to prove my point, only to discover that the lambda expression is not actually the problem. My search results on the error let me to believe that, but even using `fun x -> x.Property :> obj` does indeed still come across as a MemberAccess into my own C# code taking an expression. I apologize!